# Is Spring Data's @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) supported in Vert.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-transactions, vert.x

From what I have read so far, `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` makes use of transaction suspension capabilities in most common Java EE containers (JBoss, Glassfish, etc.)

However, as we're running Spring Data inside Vert.x, which is container-less, I'd like to find a definitive answer as to whether REQUIRES_NEW is supported in this scenario, or if we will have to use another approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring @Transactional annotations out of a JavaEE container. It will work well if you only use a database.

If you mix transactional components (a relational database **and** a message broker) then you need a transaction manager, which is often only available in JavaEE container.

I'm not a Spring or SpringBoot expert but I am pretty sure it's not difficult nowadays to add a transaction manager to a Spring/Tomcat project.

As for running Spring Data in Vert.x, it will work fine if you deploy this code in worker verticles. Check out the [spring-worker](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-worker-example) sample in the `vertx-examples` repository on GitHub